# Is there a way to initialise keras kernels for unbalanced classification?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm dealing with binary unbalanced classification and I've been using the focal loss in order to improve my results. It is mentioned in the original paper that the weights must be initialised differently with respect to the balanced binary classification problem in order to prevent instability during the training process.

This is the paper I am referring to https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02002 (section 3.3 and 4.1).

Specifically they say:

> All new conv layers except the final one in the RetinaNet subnets are initialized with bias b = 0
>   and a Gaussian weight fill with `theta = 0.01`. For the final conv
>   layer of the classification subnet, we set the bias initialization to `b = − log((1 − pi)/pi)`, where `pi` specifies that at the start of training every anchor should be labeled as foreground with confidence of `pi`. We use `pi = .01` in all experiments, although results are robust to the exact value.

Since my training is very unstable I was wondering how to initialise kernels in keras.